# Access form control from other form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I got the following method in my MDIparent1

```
public void Disablebutton()
{
    toolStripButton1.Enabled = false;
}
```

In my LoginForm OKButton click

```
MDIParent1 f1 = new MDIParent1();
f1.Disablebutton();
this.Close();
```

The LoginForm is Modal of MDIparent1.

Problem is the Disablebutton() don't works in LoginForm

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Does toolStripButton1 exist in LoginForm? You probably need to direct Disablebutton to work on the toolStripButton1 which exists inside LoginForm - there is a way to do this, but want to confirm that's your issue first.

Comment: @NWard  tootpStripButton1 is in MDIparent

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new instance of `MDIParent1` and not using the actual instance that opened `LoginForm`. You could pass the parent into the `LoginForm` constructor.

```
private MDIParent1 _parentForm = null;
public LoginForm(MDIParent1 parentForm)
{
   _parentForm = parentForm;
}

//then in whichever event you're using
_parentForm.Disablebutton();
this.Close();
```

When you want to show the `LoginForm` form, pass in the `MDIParent1` form.

```
//assuming this is in MDIParent1.cs (otherwise pass the form instance variable)
using(LoginForm lf = new LoginForm(this))
{
   lf.Show();
}
```

Comment: is that same thing with LoginForm lf = new LoginForm(); lf.ShowDialog();?

Comment: `ShowDialog` will make the parent form inaccessible until the child form is closed (it's a modal window). `Show` will allow both forms to be accessed so you can use `ShowDialog` instead if that's what you want. As an alternative to the above approach, you can set `lf.MdiParent = this` and then access the `MdiParent` property as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments, cannot convert from App.MainForm to App.MDIParent1

Comment: Did you use `LoginForm lf = new LoginForm(this)`?

Comment: I tried to use LoginForm lf = new LoginForm(this) and got same error

Comment: Instead of `this`, pass in your `MDIParent1` object, it seems you're calling the form from another place other than `MDIParent1.cs`.

Comment: I use exactly that code. NUllReferenceException was unhandle Object  reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @SquarePonge - I didn't realise you were using two different accounts, I thought you weren't OP. What's null?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your code, you are creating a new MDIParent1 window and calling DisableButton on the newly created MDIParent1 window. You have to call DisableButton on the form owning LoginForm (via the MdiParent property).

Edit: someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in your MDIchild form

```
  if(this.MdiParent is  LoginForm)
  {
     (this.MdiParent as LoginForm).Disablebutton();
  }
```